# Drupal 7 LoginToboggan username or email or custom field

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a Drupal 7 site and the client wants the user to be able to login using: email or username or a custom_field that's unique to each user.  I've scoured for solutions but can't find any.   Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using Logintoboggan to handle username or email, but can't find anything to validate and allow authentication for a custom field.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to need a custom module to form alter the login form.

Comment: use [hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) to add your new custom field and custom validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using this contrib module: https://www.drupal.org/project/login_custom_field

It will allow you to log in using a (custom user field and password) along side with (username and password). Also, you can enable [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module to allow using (email and password) as a 3rd option.